# Captcha Image not visible on Google Chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, responsive-design, captcha

I have implemented a simple captcha on my app as described on this [blog post](http://www.stefanprodan.com/2012/01/user-friendly-captcha-for-asp-net-mvc/). No change exactly the same code.

Everything works very nice with Internet Explorer 11 as well as with Firefox 35.0.1.

[image: Firefox & IE rendering]

However something bad happens with Chrome 40 as the Captcha image is not visible at all.

[image: Chrome]

I have tried to check the rendered code with the developer tool and I can even see the image by hovering on the image source attribute.

[image: Chrome developer tool]

Any suggestion on changing the code to make it working on Chrome too?

**EDIT**: I have solved the problem by removing the Bootstrap CSS `class="img-responsive"` from the markup code. However I would like to understand the reasons of this behaviour.